# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined using value as array key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the value of the input called `websitemod`, I want to put in it a value from `tab[var][1]`, where `var` is changed dynamycally depending on which option from the dropdown menu has been chosen. But, everytime I put `var val = $(this).val(); tab[val][1]`, I have an error (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`), and when I do `var = 12; tab[val][1]`, it works. I assume the jQuery function I do to assign a value to `val` is not working. Do you have an idea ?

The function itself :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // everytime the dropdown changes
    $('select[name=modservmenu]').change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();

       // changes the value of the input
       $('input[name=websitemod]').val(tab[val][1]);
    });

})
```

The tab, if you need it :

```
var tab = [
        ['10', ''],
        ['4', ''],
        ['8', ''],
        ['9', ''],
        ['11', ''],
        ['3', ''],
        ['2', ''],
        ['1', ''],
        ['6', ''],
        ['5', ''],
        ['7', ''],
        ['12', 'test.fr'],
        ];
```

EDIT :

Changed the array as suggested in the comments, with the `parseInt` it does the thing I guess

```
var tab = {
     '10' : [''],
     '4' : [''],
     '8' : [''],
     '9' : [''],
     '11' : [''],
     '3' : [''],
     '2' : [''],
     '1' : [''],
     '6' : [''],
     '5' : [''],
     '7' : [''],
     '12' : ['test.fr'],
};
```

Comment: Are you using `tab[var][1]` or `tab[val][1]`?

Comment: If `val` is a number 0 - 11 inclusive or a string that coerces to that number, the above will not cause the problem you're describing. Perhaps you meant to match `val` with the first entry in each of the subordinate arrays, rather than using it as an index into `tab`?

Comment: what are the possible values of `val`? can you share your markup?

Comment: @LostMyGlasses : corrected it, I use `tab[val][1]`

@T.J.Crowder : What I want is, whenever the dropdown menu changes, the value in the `input` changes depending on what has been selected in the dropdownmenu. Since the 1st option in it has the 1st ID, the 2nd has the 2nd ID ... I assume I can use it to have the right index into `tab`, but maybe I am wrong ?

@gurvinder372 : The values used in the dropdown menu are coming from an ID in a Database auto-incrementing it. Currently 1 to 12.

Comment: Then it might be a problem with types, as you need numeric indexes in your array. Maybe replacing `var val = $(this).val();` with `var val = parseInt($(this).val());` would fix it. Could you try it?

Comment: @LostMyGlasses JavaScript already convert indexes to string, e,g: `["bla"]['0'] // same as ["bla"][0]`

Comment: Checkout my answer

Comment: @TheProHands you're right

Comment: @LostMyGlasses And in fact, it's exactly the opposite: What people think are numeric indexes into arrays are actually string property names in an object, with JS's standard arrays: [*A myth of arrays*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)

Comment: @LostMyGlasses : at the exact moment you were writing this answer, I found the same solution, and it works ! I suppose when I do `$(this).val()`, it extracts a string, and I need an int to use as a key for my array.

Thank you ! guys !

Comment: Wherever array's are indexed internally as strings, is actually irrelevant to the problem here.  The list is an array of object literals, ideally you would want the array to be flattered so you can do Object literal lookups,  eg. sub['12'], the 12 here is not the index / but a key reference.  it may as well have been  sub['option1']  etc..

Comment: Slight wording error last, it's "The list is an array of arrays", and ideally want to be a fattened object literal. `var tabIdx = tab.reduce(function (a,b) { a[b[0]] = b[1]; return a; }, {});` would do the trick.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I had no idea about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing here, you cannot access an array's cell via a value of a cell's cell. Also your "val" is a string but "tab" is an array so it uses indexes and indexes are integers. You can access array via it's indexes like array[0]. So you are confusing on "indexes" <--> "values"

In detail, let's say you want to get the element "12" and you are accessing it like array[12] but it's index is "11" so you can access it via the index of it like array[11] --> gives you "["12", "test.fr"]" then you can use this array object. Sample:

```
//let's say value is 12
tab["12"] --> null

//let's get the array contains value "12"
tab[11] --> ["12", "test.fr"],
//let's access to "test.fr"
tab[11][1] --> "test.fr"
```

And, this null objects index "1" is undefined so you got your error "*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined*"

```
tab["12"][1] //--> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

Your `tab` object is not a map so you cannot access it via "string" values. So you have to create an object like the below one to access it via text indexes and after that, you can access an array index (what ever index you want):

```js
var tab = {
        '10' : ['', ''],
        '4': ['', ''],
        '8': ['', ''],
        '9': ['', ''],
        '11': ['', ''],
        '3': ['', ''],
        '2': ['', ''],
        '1': ['', ''],
        '6': ['', ''],
        '5': ['', ''],
        '7': ['', ''],
        '12': ['', 'test.fr'],
        };

$(document).ready(function () {

    // everytime the dropdown changes
    $('select[name=modservmenu]').change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();

       // changes the value of the input
       $('input[name=websitemod]').val(tab[val][1]);
    });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="modservmenu">
  <option>10</option>
  <option>12</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="websitemod"/>
```

Or, you can use your array and search it like this:

```js
var tab = [
        ['10', ''],
        ['4', ''],
        ['8', ''],
        ['9', ''],
        ['11', ''],
        ['3', ''],
        ['2', ''],
        ['1', ''],
        ['6', ''],
        ['5', ''],
        ['7', ''],
        ['12', 'test.fr'],
        ];

$(document).ready(function () {

    // everytime the dropdown changes
    $('select[name=modservmenu]').change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
  
        for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
          if (tab[i][0] == val) {
            $('input[name=websitemod]').val(tab[i][1]);
            break;
          }
        }
    });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="modservmenu">
  <option>10</option>
  <option>12</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="websitemod"/>
```

Comment: This is correct, but you don't know if the op code is trying to access nested arrays by indexes.

Comment: Yes but according to the low detailed question, this answer got much more than the expected.

Comment: It could be a little tricky for the OP to re-write all hist tab data, so instead you could create a simple transform -> var tabIdx = tab.reduce(function (a,b) { a[b[0]] = b[1]; return a; }, {});   tabIdx will then be in the format  {"10":"", "12": "test.fr"}   btw.  Not sure why you have been downvoted, it was certainly a useful post.

Comment: Did you check my comment in the question comments? *"JavaScript already convert indexes to string, e,g: `['bla']['0'] // same as ['bla'][0]`"*. The edit is a bit incorrect, anyway +1 for being the best answer in here

Comment: Yes corrected it, and also gave as much as information I can give

Comment: This is correct for the `string` part, and your solution is correct and working as well. I've found that doing a simple `var val = parseInt($(this).val());` works like a charm ! Thank you :)

Comment: So @TheProHands strings are not the same with the integers as @ Prototype says.

Comment: @webmaster No, -_- I said indexes are string in JavaScript. Always that we index a object with any expression using . or [...] the identifier/value inside the expression converts to a string, and this is true. Test the code in my comment first.

Comment: `['bla']['0'] // same as ['bla'][0]`

Comment: Yeah I guess ı didn't understand you clearly, let's concentrate on the question, so here parseInt method solved Prototype's problem and parseInt is a method that converts string into integer and there Prototype is trying to access to the index of an array, so why here string is not working?

Comment: Yeah ok understood, you are right, in one point, because yes the index is always string "if you use index". By index, you are using a "map" there. Sample: var a = {}; a["x"] = "b"; a[3] = "z". But, here, the difference is, the pre-created object is a pure array like var array = ["a", "b", "c"]. Here, the objects are kept sequentially, with indexes and indexes are numbers, I mean integers. The difference is "initiation style". If you initiate an array like this, it will definitely use integers as indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you said:

> The values used in the dropdown menu are coming from an ID in a Database auto-incrementing it. Currently 1 to 12.

Okay, so that means [I guessed right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916474/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-1-of-undefined-using-value-as-array-k/39917111#comment67116955_39916474), and you can't use `val` to directly index into your `tab` array. Instead, you need to find the entry in your `tab` array that has `val` as the first argument. Fortunately, arrays have just the thing: `find`:

```
var entry = tab.find(function(e) { return e[0] == val; });
```

Note that `Array#find` is relatively new, but [can be polyfilled on older browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
var tab = [
  ['10', ''],
  ['4', ''],
  ['8', ''],
  ['9', ''],
  ['11', ''],
  ['3', ''],
  ['2', ''],
  ['1', ''],
  ['6', ''],
  ['5', ''],
  ['7', ''],
  ['12', 'test.fr'],
];

$(document).ready(function() {

  // everytime the dropdown changes
  $('select[name=modservmenu]').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    // changes the value of the input
    var entry = tab.find(function(e) { return e[0] == val; });
    if (entry) {
      $('input[name=websitemod]').val(entry[1]);
    }
  });

})
```

```html
<select name="modservmenu">
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="12">Twelve</option>
</select>
<input name="websitemod">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

You shouldn't use 'var' as a variable name, it's a reserved keyword in javascript (maybe it's not in your script, just in your post)

Check the type of your array keys.

```
tab[12][1]
```

may be not the same as

```
tab['12'][1]
```

Maybe you just need

```
var val = parseInt($(this).val());
```